# Incorrect code line number in log file after application is deployed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logfile

I write the log file by using log4net. So for keep tracking, every line of log contains the code line number. In my coding, I get the file line number with the statement below:

```
 int codeLine = (new StackFrame(0, true).GetFileLineNumber()) + 1;
```

Everything works fine when I run in debug mode, but I just realized that after my application is deployed, all the code line number in the log file becomes 1. How can I get the correct code line number after the application is deployed?

Comment: the documentation say: `This information is typically extracted from the debugging symbols for the executable`.  I'd imagine that this wouldn't work with a release build?

Comment: so is it I have to do it one by one? I mean state the line number one by one in the coding.

Comment: Did you include the .pdb files next to the assemblies?

Comment: Hi @ Mikanikal, nope...is it I need to include the .pdb file?

Comment: Hi @Mikanikal, after I include the .pdb file, it works....thanks ya

Comment: @YWah, You're welcome. I posted it as an answer so you can accept it and anyone else viewing will be able to find it and have similar results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .pdb file next to the release assembly will allow the logging to read the correct (originally written) line numbers. Just place the .pdb next to the assembly.